# Xamarin Forms dependency service don't work with generics?

Tags: xamarin, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get an instance of generic class in Xamarin.Forms. If I use the code below everything works fine:

> **Interface**
>
> ```
> namespace PrismNinjectApp1.Application.Interfaces
> {
>     public interface IUserService { }
> }
> ```
>
> **Concrete class**
>
> ```
> [assembly: Dependency(typeof(PrismNinjectApp1.Application.DomainServices.UserService))]
> namespace PrismNinjectApp1.Application.DomainServices
> {
>     public class UserService : IUserService
>     {
>         public UserService() { }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **View Model**
>
> ```
> namespace PrismNinjectApp1.ViewModels
> {
>     public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
>     {
>         private readonly IUserService _userService;
>
>         public MainPageViewModel()
>         {
>             _userService = DependencyService.Get<IUserService>();
>         }
>         //Implementation of INavigationAware interface (I'm using Prism)
>     }
> }
> ```

But if I try do the same with generics I can't get the object instance:

> **Interface**
>
> ```
> namespace PrismNinjectApp1.test
> {
>     public interface IMyInterface<T> where T : class { }
> }
> ```
>
> **Concrete class**
>
> ```
> [assembly: Dependency(typeof(PrismNinjectApp1.test.MyInterface<>))]
> namespace PrismNinjectApp1.test
> {
>     public class MyInterface<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T : class { }
> }
> ```
>
> **View Model**
>
> ```
> namespace PrismNinjectApp1.ViewModels
> {
>     public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
>     {
>         private readonly IMyInterface<Users> _myInterface;
>
>         public MainPageViewModel()
>         {
>             _myInterface = DependencyService.Get<IMyInterface<Users>>(); //Gets NULL value
>         }
>         //Implementation of INavigationAware interface (I'm using Prism)
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **Users** class is a domain entity
>
> ```
> public class Users
>     {
>         [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
>         public int Id { get; set; }
>         [MaxLength(100)]
>         public string Name { get; set; }
>     }
> ```

Any idea how I can get this object instance?

I trying to do this because I want to use generics services and repositories with basic CRUD and search methods with this structure

1. App (project droid and ios)
2. Shared (portable project)
3. Application (for external services - portable projec)
4. Domain - (portable project)
5. Data - (portable project)

**Xamarin Forms version:** 2.3.4.247

Comment: Have you found the solution? really appreciate if you could share.